# Python logger with multiple modules

Tags: python, logging

I want to create my custom logger class

```
import logging
class mylooger():
   def __init__(module_name):
       logger=logging.getlogger(module_name)
```

And i want use logger in my main file and two other files

```
main.py
test1.py
test2.py
```

i want to decide my logfile path in main.py and keep main.py, test1.py and test2.py file log in same file.

Now suppose later i want to import test1.py and test2.py in some other file e.g main1.py. So i want to decide my logfile path from main1.py and keep main1.py, test1.py and test2.py log in same file.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. `logger` is just a local variable to `__init__`, and `getLogger` already returns a reference to a unique `Logger` object based on its argument.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how stdlib logging is designed.  If you want to use the same logger in multiple modules, just get the same logger:

```
# in main.py
logger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")

def main():
    ...
    logging.basicConfig(...)
    logger.info("some event")
```

And:

```
# in test1.py
logger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")

def some_lib_function():
    ...
    logger.debug("some other event")
```

The logging framework itself maintains a global mutable state so that these are resolving to the same loggers and hence the same formatters/handlers.